# Want to pass a filepath as a parameter to a stored procedure but is saving to the default location and naming it the first letter of the parameter

Tags: sql, ado

Instead of creating the backup at the specified filepath, which works when being run just as a normal query in SSMS, it creates the backup in the default location and calls the file 'N' in this case but when I have change the file path to remove the N it then calls it an apostraphe.

My Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BackUpTo]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FilePath nvarchar 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    -- N'c:\temp\backups\lob_backup.bak'
    BACKUP DATABASE [lob]
    TO DISK = @FilePath
END
```

Calling in my test :

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BackUpTo", conn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter filepath = cmd.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    filepath.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    filepath.Value = @"N'c:\temp\backups\lob_backup.bak'";

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

finally
{
        conn.Close();
}
```

Edit:

Solution as pointed out by HoneyBadger was that I hadn't set a length and therefore was defaulting to 1 (the first character).

Comment: You haven't given your `@FilePath` variable a length, so it defaults to 1. So you are actually calling your procedure with parameter `@FilePath = 'N'`.

Comment: Thanks! that's what it is.

Comment: @HoneyBadger that just fixed the issue I was having too.  Stick your comment up as the answer and I'll give it an upvote!